# New AngularJS DataGrid and Framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable, datagrid, pivot-table

### AngularJS framework, AngularJS DataGrid

I need your opinions as web developers about the framework I built in the last two years. Please visit [Presentation site](http://ax-frmk.ionescu.io/?so#!/ax-frmk/features)
and put here your opinions (pro or contra).
This contain a complex Data grid (with virtual rows and columns scroll, pivot table, pinned columns left,right, auto generated row editor) with other some features I didn't seen at other javascript DataGrid (profile, more customization on grouping records).
I tried to create something real simple to understand and implement, and very flexible.You'll decide if I succeeded :).
I didn't finish adaptation for mobile devices.
If you like it,  I'll make it available for you.
I posted to github all presentation site sources: [AxFrmk repo](https://github.com/bogdanim36/ax-frmk)

DataGrid configuration popup:
[image: DataGrid configuration popup]

Invoice editing:
[image: Invoice editing]

Invoice excel export:
[image: Exporting in excel]

Comment: is modular ? easy to use ?

Comment: You can take a look how the implementation is in Show case folder of presentation site. DataGrid has a lot of methods which can be customized. I wanted to be the easiest from all existing framework.